# What does "type=1" mean in a .wav file?

Tags: audio, wav

If you unpack the data in a wav file between bytes 20 and 35 inclusive (I think) you get different values for type, channels, samplerate, bytespersec, alignment and bits.

```
[type] => 1
[channels] => 1
[samplerate] => 8000
[bytespersec] => 16000
[alignment] => 2
[bits] => 16
```

What does type=1 mean? Is there a type = 2? If there is, is that still a wav file? I'm trying to ask Google and I keep getting results like "What is a wav file?" that don't mention anything I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 seems to imply the data is in the PCM format. Other values would indicate some other format.

http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

```
20        2   AudioFormat      PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
```

Comment: Did you find this on Google? If so, they have more respect for you intellect than they do for mine.

Comment: I did. But I think it's just about learning Google's search syntax.